# How can I build a vector whose data is pointed to an array, and is this possible for unified memory?

Tags: c++, cuda

We know that if we have a vector like

```
std::vector<int> a_vector;
```

and this vector has elements, we can have the array of elements from

```
int *the_array= a_vector.data();
```

My question is: How can we do the opposite?

```
int the_array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

std::vector<int> a_vector;

a_vector.data=the_array; //this does not seem to work
```

To clarify, I don't wish to *copy* the values , nor create an array *from * the values but have them in the same memory area.

Also ,  why am I asking this?

I would like to have this original array, in a managed (unified) area of memory

```
__device__ __managed__ int the_array[5];
```

and build the vector to point there.

Comment: You could probably do it with a custom allocator, but, why go to the effort?  Plus you wouldn't be able to expand the vector.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049657/stack-buffer-based-stl-allocator

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (c++20) might be a better "container" for this.

Comment: Firstly, `int *the_array={1,2,3,4,5}` is invalid.   Second, if you want to control where the data managed by a `std::vector` resides, use a custom allocator.    If you want to create an array of automatic storage duration, and then have a `std::vector` manage that array, my guess is that an allocator for the job will be a hairy job (lots of possibilities of introducing undefined behaviour in response to innocent operations by other code on the vector).

Comment: There is also `boost::static_vector`, if boost is your thing.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/21163028/1607937

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21918950/1863938

Comment: In the latest versions of thrust, a thrust vector can be of a [universal_vector type](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/support-for-cuda-unified-memory-now-available-in-thrust/), which means that it is using a managed allocator.

Answer (score 1):

> we can have the array of elements from

What we get from `std::vector::data` is a pointer to the first element.

> My question is: How can we do the opposite?
>
> ```
> a_vector.data=the_array; //this does not seem to work
> ```

No. Only way for a vector to take ownership of an array like that is from another vector of same type.

Comment: so I guess the question is if I can define vectors in managed memory...

Comment: @KansaiRobot
Perhaps by writing a custom allocator that calls `cudaMallocManaged`. I don't have experience with that though.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to construct a `vector` with already allocated memory would somewhat defeat the RAI design principle which is propably the reason it's isn't part of the `std::vector` API.

If all you need is a nice modern C++ interface to your allocated memory, `span` would be the right choice. You don't need to wait for NVIDIA to implement C++20, but could use the [gsl-lite](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite) implementation of `span` which provides `__host__ __device__` member functions such that you can use their `span` inside (or as arguments to) kernels as well.

If you want an actual container (not a view), which manages the memory (also allocates it), [Thrust](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust) would be the obvious choice. While it was possible before to use their `device_vector` with a custom allocator, nowadays they provide a `universal_vector` for unified memory.